# Is the leveling system in World of Warcraft designed assuming players typically complete only some of the quests?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm playing for the first time. I generally complete every quest before moving on to a new zone. I've found that as I neared completion of BC content on Outland, I'm close to level 80, while most of the sources online indicate that BC takes you from level 60-70. Am I an outlier or is this to be expected? Do people typically skip entire zones of content or complete only 60-70% of available quests?

Comment: Once you're so many levels above a quest's set range (I forget the exact number), you don't gain XP from that quest (it'll be gray in your quest log). If you're close to 80, you're probably not even getting XP from the quests in Outland anymore.

Comment: Recommend if you play this way, you look up the level of the area and/or level of the expansion and freeze your character to not gain any xp.  That way you won't be so overpowered for the area (though frozen characters still get more powerful just not the same scale).  For new player, unless you have a friend supplying gold this is probably only advisable at the end of every xpac.  It will allow you to farm gold a bit up without advancing as well (though gold gathering scales to quest level as well).

Comment: @challen I'm pretty sure this is not true.  I'm playing a level 50 through some of the lower level redone cata areas and the char is advancing albeit really slowly.  I do think it scales though.

Comment: You're right. Gray quests do give XP but it's reduced from the regular amount.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

World of Warcraft has always been designed so that you wouldn't have to visit every zone to progress.

This is most evident in the old world, both pre- and post-Cataclysm where you have several branching paths you could take.  An example of this for Horde exists at level 10, where from Orgrimmar you can choose to go south-west into Northern Barrens or north into Azshara... or south from Undercity into Silverpine Forest.

In addition, Blizzard has dramatically increased how quickly you level at levels below 90*, meaning that you sometimes only need 1-2 zones per expansion to hit that expansion's level cap and move on to the next area.

*Note, it's 90 now because that's the lowest level for Warlords of Draenor, the newest expansion out at the time of this writing.

Comment: Just for info, post Draenor, I leveled my 85 rogue to 90 in Pandaria by visiting Jade Forest, Kun-lai Summit and Dread Wastes and never fully completing quest chains in these zones either. That is visiting 3 of the 7 Pandaria release zones. My character had the full amount of rested XP, but no heirlooms or other XP buffs.

Comment: @Lyrical Same time period, I leveled my 85 Warlock to 90 through Jade Forest, Valley of the Four Winds, and Krasarang Wilds (which doesn't have that many quests to speak of).

Answer (score 2):

The quests are only one way of levelling: thus, Blizzard don't expect you to complete all the quests.

You can level via dungeons, quests, battlegrounds, etc. If it was the only way of levelling, they would expect you to finish main storyline quests (this is how it is for the current expansion always, so you can unlock things) but it's not. Quite a lot of quests aren't 'main' quests, either, so they don't really expect you to do everything.

Also, you get xp from killing monsters, doing professions, etc, all of which you do alongside questing. It can't be fine-tuned like that.

As Powerlord said, older expansion's levelling curves have been altered so you get to new content far faster. This means you don't have to do most things (I managed to hit 90 on an alt (questing, I normally level via dungeons) without leaving WotLK zones) to get to current content, or level cap.

Once you get to Draenor, you still have the options, but you are expected to do questing to get content, and levelling is far slower.